# XML-parsing respecting empty elements in between ("<lb/>") in Pyhton/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I need to parse XML-documents with `BeautifulSoup` in `Python3` to get all values from attributes — seperated from each other by empty elements (nested or not). It is easy to fetch *all* values at once, but I need them seperated.

Please see the MWE below: I need all `val`-Values from the `c`-elements seperated by `lb`- or `pb`-elements. The list output now is: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, but I need a list of lists like `[[1, 2], [3,4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]` (or a `dict`).

The problem, I think, is, that I can't relate to the next empty-element (it's not a `sibling` and not the `next_element`).

Thank you for your help!

**MWE-XML-example: "file.xml"**

```xml
<text>
 <nested>
  <c val="1">A</c>
  <c val="2">B</c>
 </nested>
 <lb/>
 <nested>
  <nested>
   <c val="3">C</c>
   <c val="4">D</c>
   <lb/>
   <pb/>
   <c val="5">E</c>
   <c val="6">F</c>
   <c type="empty"> </c>
  </nested>
 </nested>
 <lb/>
 <c val="7">G</c>
 <c val="8">H</c>
</text>
```

**MWE-python3-example**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("file.xml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fh.read(), "lxml-xml")
    listoflists = list()
    val_list = list()

    for c in soup.find_all("c"):

        if not "val" in c.attrs:
            continue

        else:
            val_list.append( int(c["val"]) )

        if c.next_sibling == (soup.lb or soup.pb): # <-- not working?
            listoflists.append(val_list)
            continue

    print(val_list)
    print(listoflists)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group your elements.

For example (if `txt` is your code snippet from the question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')

out = []
for v, g in groupby(soup.select('c[val], lb, pb'), lambda k: k.name == 'c'):
    if v:
        out.append([c['val'] for c in g])

print(out)
```

This prints:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

---

EDIT (version without `.select()`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')

out = []
for v, g in groupby(soup.find_all(['c', 'lb', 'pb']), lambda k: k.name == 'c'):
    if v:
        out.append([c['val'] for c in g if 'val' in c.attrs])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why, but it outputs `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']]` for me.

Comment: Yes, it's the same file/content.

Comment: @dia Then it should print same output as mine. Check your `bs4` version (should be `4.8.2`)

Comment: Okay, my version is `4.6.0`. But updating my system/python etc. doesn't update `bs4`. (working in linux / `apt-get`.) — Is there another solution? (I have to run this over 2 gb of xml files.)

Comment: @dia `4.6.0` is old version. You can try `sudo pip install bs4 -U` or use virtual environment and install `bs4` and other packages there.

Comment: @dia I added version without `.select()`, maybe it will work with the old version of `bs4`. See my edit.

Comment: Andrej, no worries, the older version works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you a library, not relying on third-party libraries, lighter and faster.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
from itertools import groupby
html ='''
<text>
 <nested>
  <c val="1">A</c>
  <c val="2">B</c>
 </nested>
 <lb/>
 <nested>
  <nested>
   <c val="3">C</c>
   <c val="4">D</c>
   <lb/>
   <pb/>
   <c val="5">E</c>
   <c val="6">F</c>
   <c type="empty"> </c>
  </nested>
 </nested>
 <lb/>
 <c val="7">G</c>
 <c val="8">H</c>
</text>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# First
out = []
for v, g in groupby(doc.getElementsByTag(['c','lb','pb']), lambda k: k.tag == 'c'):
    if v:
        out.append([c['val'] for c in g if 'val' in c])
print(out)

# Second
listoflists = list()
val_list = list()
lstC = doc.cs.contains('',attr='val')
for c in lstC:
  val_list.append(int(c["val"]))
  next = c.next
  if not next or not next.val:
    listoflists.append(val_list)
    val_list = list()
print (listoflists)
```

Result:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```